# ¿Cómo asignar un Background Image según una condicion en Android?

Tags: java, android

Quiero asignar una imagen de fondo a un layout según el valor que tome la variable nivel en cada momento.

Si nivel=1 entonces debe asignar img_1

Si nivel=500 entonces debe asignar img_500
....

```
int nivel=225; //Ejemplo.
lyimg = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyimg);

    //Creo mi array
    final String[][] numimg = new String[500][500];

    //Guardo cada una de las imagenes (serán más de 500)
    for (int contador = 1; contador < 500; ++contador) {
        numimg[contador][1] = "img_"+contador;
        numimg[contador][2] = ""+contador;
    }

    //Asigno la imagen según el nivel, cualquier combinacion.
    if(){lyimg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.numimg[nivel][1]);} // <-Esto me da error
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Serán cientos de combinaciones asi que no me vale tener cientos de IFs.

Comment: porque usas una matriz para las imagenes? no es mas facil llamarlas directamente ?

Comment: Como sería? @BrunoSosaFastTag

Comment: te deje una respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los recursos se manejan por `Ids` que son generados en el diseñador de recursos de tu app. Si lo que quieres es obtener cada id de la imagen almacenada en tu carpeta drawable, intenta lo siguiente:

```
ArrayList<int> ids = new ArrayList<>();

for (int contador = 0; contador < niveles; ++contador) {

      int id = getResources().getIdentifier("img_"+contador, "drawable", this.getPackageName());

      // En este punto id tendrá el id de referencia de la imagen o devolvera 0 si no la encuentra
      if(id != 0)
         ids.add(id);
}

// nivel - 1 porque la lista comienza en 0
lyimg.setBackgroundResource(ids[nivel-1]);
```

La variable `niveles` debe tener el valor exacto de niveles, mientras que nivel debe ser el nivel de cual se va a cargar la imagen. Para que el algoritmo funcione. Debes asegurarte que el arreglo tenga la misma cantidad de elementos que niveles. De lo contrario (si no encuentra alguna imagen con dicho nombre) deberas restar a la variable `nivel`. `nivel - 1 - (niveles - ids.length)` o crear un diccionario o `HashMap` en vez de un `ArrayList`, donde el `Key` sea tipo `String` donde se guardara `"img_"+contador` y el `value` tipo `int` donde guardaras el `id` del recurso. Porque solo habran `ids.length` cantidades de imagenes validas en `niveles` y es la unica manera se asegurarte que el nivel que quieres cargar, sea el mismo que obtienes de tu lista cuando no se encuentra algunos de los recursos dentro del `for`.

Ahora bien,  no te recomiendo es cargar toda la cantidad de imágenes que dices ya que si manejan una resolucion un poco alta. Puede traerte problemas de memoria y tendrias que utilizar librerias como `Glide` o crear un algoritmo para reciclar las imagenes cargadas.

Comment: Wooo gracias, con eso no necesito ni el for. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @AntonioRuiz actualice el codigo para que no tengas que hacer ni un if para asignar la imagen segun el nivel.

Answer (score 1):

Para colocar una imagen u otra en Java  podrias hacer algo asi como

```
Context context = this;
if(condicion){    
      lyimg.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.img1)); 
} 
else
{   
      lyimg.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.img2)); 
}
```

Asi ya bastaria para que te funcione

Si tienes muchas imagenes y no quieres utilizar ifs / else podrias usar un switch

```
      switch(valorDelaCondicion) {
                    case "1" :
                        lyimg.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.img1)); 

                        break;
                    case "2" :
                         lyimg.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.img2)); 
                        break;
            default :
                    System.out.println("Invalid grade");
            }
```

Comment: Eso no me sirve porque tengo cientos de combinanciones, nivel=1, nivel=2, nivel=3, nivel=500. No puedo tener 500 IF.

Comment: puedes utilizar nombres que sea numericos y con un while vas colocandolos , si quieres una respuesta concreta debes ser mas especifico que es lo que tenes  y que queres hacer

Comment: Perfectamente podrias tener un switch , te edite la respuesta

Comment: con un switch no tendría más de 500 cases? estaría en las mismas.

Comment: explicame por favor mas concretamente el problema e intento darte una respuesta mas orientada

Comment: He actualizado el post principal, no obstante trataré de explicarme mejor. Tengo una variable "nivel" que puede tomar cualquier valor del 1 al 500 y según esta variable quiero que se guarde un background con la imagen que ya tengo subida con ese mismo número en el nombre, "img_X".

Comment: Más fácil, si nivel es igual a 225, debería poner de background a la imagen "img_225". Y para ello no puedo tener ni 225 cases ni 225 IFs.